# The touch of death

Tags: snakemake

Should the file `foo.txt` already exist before running the following Snakefile

```
rule master :
        output :
                touch('foo.txt')

        input : 'task.done'

rule task :
        output :
                touch('task.done')

        shell : 'echo "bar" > foo.txt'
```

it is clear that there is

```
Nothing to be done.
```

and the contents of `foo.txt` remain unaltered.  Should the file `foo.txt` *not* exist before running this Snakefile, it is created with the text "bar" by `rule task`, but then this is erased by the touch of `rule master`.  There is even the appropriate warning

```
Warning: the following output files of rule master were not present when the DAG was created:
{'foo.txt'}
Touching output file foo.txt.
```

I understand perfectly what is going on, but *why* does snakemake do this?  Why can `touch` do more than just "touch" a file in certain contexts?

### UPDATE:

Ok, thanks to a helpful comment, this does not really have to do specifically with `touch`, and is rather a question about untracked files (maybe a change of title should be in order), in particular those *not present when the DAG was created*, as clearly mentioned in the Warning.  For example, if the above Snakefile is instead

```
rule master :
        output : 'foo.txt'

        input : 'task.done'

rule task :
        output :
                touch('task.done')

        shell : 'echo "bar" > foo.txt'
```

I now get:

```
Warning: the following output files of rule master were not present when the DAG was created:
{'foo.txt'}
Waiting at most 5 seconds for missing files.
MissingOutputException in line 1 of /home/patterson/snaketest/touch-of-death.snake:
Missing files after 5 seconds:
foo.txt
This might be due to filesystem latency. If that is the case, consider to increase the wait time with --latency-wait.
```

Which again, is perfectly understandable behavior: I get the warning about the file `foo.txt` which was not there before the creation of the DAG, and then it waits for `foo.txt`, which not the target of any rule, and so snakemake does not see it: it is technically missing according to snakemake.

I agree that the above is an example of bad design, and that it is because I am playing the devil's advocate in trying to understand why snakemake operates like this.

Let's say then, for argument, that one could have snakemake pay attention to files that are created during the workflow --- again, I believe that one could somehow force this behavior with `checkpoints` (re-evaluation of the DAG at runtime), but let's say I do not want to do this either --- even an example, where one could really shoot oneself badly in the foot with a (bad) design as it is above, would be welcome.

I realize that this could be related to why `dynamic` files is now deprecated in snakemake (in favor of `checkpoints`), but also because of inherent limitations regarding concurrent processes in python (cf. https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing.html), since snakemake is written in python after all.

Comment: Just to be clear, the context in this case is that file `foo.txt` was not present when the DAG was created.  Indeed, the above situation could be avoided by doing something fancy with checkpoints (re-evaluating the DAG at runtime), and accessing the `glob_wildcards` object, and so this is a question about the design of snakemake --- why this behaviour?

Answer (score 3):

After discussion with OP it is now clear to me that the specific question was why foo.txt gets overwritten by snakemake with an empty file, and not just 'touched'. This is because the 'foo.txt' file made by 'task' is not tracked and thus upon execution of the 'master' rule it gets deleted, because snakemake considers it old. The `touch('foo.txt')` then gets evaluated and creates a new empty file. This behaviour ensures a clean execution of the rule.

Answer (score 1):

Output keywords should not include an operation such as touch, as this is what "run:" or "shell:" is for. The output and input keywords  should only contain actual files to be used or be created. Also in rule "task" you are trying to define "task.done" as your output, but you tell it to make "foo.txt". Snakemake obviously gets confused and tells you so.

Consider instead:

```
rule master :
    input : 'foo.txt'
    output : 'task.done'
    run:
           touch(output[0])

rule task :
        output : 'foo.txt'
        shell : 'echo "bar" > {output}'
```

'task' creates foo.txt, and 'master' creates task.done if the 'task' rule was successful.

Comment: Please note that my goal is to understand _why_ the `touch` of snakemake does not always simply "touch" a file (like _e.g._, in the linux OS), but rather can clobber a file in certain contexts, and this is a minimal example which seems to exhibit this departure from the expected behavior.  Furthermore, output keywords indeed _may_ contain an operation such as touch: https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#flag-files --- if I understand correctly, ```output: touch('file')```, is short for the lines ```output: 'file'``` and ```run: touch(output[0])```

Comment: Ah, now I get the problem. It may have to do with that foo.txt is labeled as output for the 'master' rule, and not in the 'task' rule. Thus the foo.txt made by 'task' is not tracked by snakemake, is older than the execution of 'master' and thus gets recreated, wiping out the contents created by 'task'.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is precisely what is happening (even with the appropriate warning) --- and then what perplexes me is that, with `foo.txt` being older than the execution of `master`, rule `master` should indeed touch `foo.txt`, but it should only "touch" it, _i.e._, simply update only the timestamp, while leaving the file contents intact --- as one would expect in _e.g._, the linux OS.  Given this warning, I'm led to believe that this is on purpose, _i.e._, it is _by design_ ... but why?

Comment: Because foo.txt is marked as output for 'master' snakemake will first delete the old version and then performs 'touch' to make a new one. I think this is prefered behaviour to ensure a clean execution of a rule, but for a full answer you will need to ask the developers directly. But as I said before, creating a file in a rule while not marking it as output in that rule is bad snakemake workflow design and should be avoided at all costs, especially if you are going to use that file in another rule as well. Unintended use will generate unintended side effects.

Comment: Yes, that is a good point: it has nothing to do with touch, in fact, but is rather an issue of untracked files --- in particular, those which where not present when the DAG was created (as the warning states)

Comment: I've posted the outcome of our discussion as an answer, so readers don't need to read the comments to find it. Please consider flagging it as the correct answer.